# Dynamically create preference subscreens without PreferenceFragments from multiple xml files?

Tags: android

Can I use a combination of xml defined preferences and create a small section of them dynamically?

Example:
I have the following settings.xml file defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceScreen android:key="Menu1" android:title="Menu1" android:persistent="false" >
        <CheckBoxPreference  android:key="item1" android:title="@string/lesson1" android:summary="@string/summary" android:defaultValue="false"/>
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="item2" android:title="@string/lesson2" android:summary="@string/summary" android:defaultValue="false"/>
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="item3" android:title="@string/lesson3" android:summary="@string/summary"  android:defaultValue="false"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
    <PreferenceScreen android:key="menu2" android:title="Menu2" android:persistent="false">
        <CheckBoxPreference  android:key="item1" android:title="@string/lesson1" android:summary="@string/summary" android:defaultValue="false"/>
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="item2" android:title="@string/lesson2" android:summary="@string/summary" android:defaultValue="false"/>
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="item3" android:title="@string/lesson3" android:summary="@string/summary"  android:defaultValue="false"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
    <PreferenceScreen android:key="menu3" android:title="Menu3" android:persistent="false">
        <CheckBoxPreference  android:key="item1" android:title="@string/lesson1" android:summary="@string/summary" android:defaultValue="false"/>
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="item2" android:title="@string/lesson2" android:summary="@string/summary" android:defaultValue="false"/>
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="item3" android:title="@string/lesson3" android:summary="@string/summary"  android:defaultValue="false"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Can I use the in conjunction with the onCreate() method here:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    PreferenceScreen prefs = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
    prefs.setKey("menu4");
    prefs.setTitle("Menu4");

    //How to add prefs as the next item in preferences menu??
}
```

I have a API level 8 requirement so I can't use PreferenceFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct way to do this:

```
    PreferenceScreen main = ((PreferenceScreen)findPreference("MAINMENU"));
    main.addPreference(prefs);
```

I found it in this Stack Overflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5437844/2994645