# Add values to xml file on android

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

Is is possible to add new values in List Preference in for example pref_data_sync.xml from code in Android app. If yes, how to get the date from this file?

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: You want to dynamically build a preference XML? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot modify a `xml` preferences file. You cannot modify a resource android file by code.

But if you want to append it using code you can do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5437844/3482000